# Ghub Lua script used to work, but all of a sudden stopped

Tags: lua, logitech

I have this lua and it worked just fine back in may, then yesterday I came back to test it out after several months not used, and now, nothing, did anything change in Ghub/Lua?

This is the script:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
  if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
  elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
    ReleaseMouseButton(2) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
  end
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 7) then
    recoil = not recoil
  end
  if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 and recoil) then
    if recoil then
      repeat
        Sleep(18)
        MoveMouseRelative(0,2)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end
  end
end
```

I tried reinstalling Logitech Ghub several times including reboots, nothing changed.

*EDIT* I added this at the top of my script, and it seems to have done the trick.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current version of GHub the `PROFILE_ACTIVATED` event has its second parameter `arg=nil` (in the previous versions `arg` was `0`), so you must replace

```
OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
```

with either

```
OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, tostring(arg))
```

or

```
OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg or 0)
```

Without such modification, all your GHub scripts now fail to handle events `PROFILE_ACTIVATED` and `PROFILE_DEACTIVATED` as the code generates an exception at the line `OutputLogMessage`.